# Loop JSON Data after Succes from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON data looks like this :

```
{
    "kode_pesanan":"P000000033",
    "lat":"4.454274",
    "lng":"96.152699",
    "sort":0,
    "gambar":"\/status_image\/persiapanbiru.png"
}
```

This is the `json_encode` :

```
echo json_encode(
               array(
                    "kode_pesanan"=>$data['kode_pesanan'],
                    "lat"=>$data['lat_antar'],
                    "lng"=>$data['ltd_antar'],
                    "sort"=>$i,
                    "gambar"=>$status
                    )
               );
```

I have trying with `for` and `$.each` statements but didn't work.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var json = {"kode_pesanan":"P000000033","lat":"4.454274","lng":"96.152699","sort":0,"gambar":"\/status_image\/persiapanbiru.png"}
console.log(json);
//json = $.parseJSON(json);
$.each( json , function(e,v) {
 console.log(e,v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`$.each( json , function(e,v)` => `e` is the key and `v` is the value of the `json` object

Comment: I've got this : TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Comment: I've got this now : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 129 of the JSON data

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: This is one of the better ways of looping around a JSON.

Comment: I've got this : Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"kode_pesanan":"P000000062","lat":"-6.239092274994336","lng":"106.65475845336914","sort":0,"gambar":"\/status_image\/blue.png"}

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for me? @LeonardFebrianto

Comment: im sorry i don't understand using fiddle yet

Comment: Do you have your dataType as `dataType : "JSON"` in your ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128117/discussion-between-aniket-sahrawat-and-leonard-febrianto).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var json = {"kode_pesanan":"P000000033","lat":"4.454274","lng":"96.152699","sort":0,"gambar":"\/status_image\/persiapanbiru.png"};

$.each(json,function(i,val){
console.log(i+' ==> '+val);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jquery and want to print one by one value without looping then use the following method for single array in JSON :

```
    var json = {"kode_pesanan":"P000000033","lat":"4.454274","lng":"96.152699","sort":0,"gambar":"\/status_image\/persiapanbiru.png"};
   console.log(json.kode_pesanan);
```

// And you can use for loop for multidimensional json array and then can print one by one value for each row using json object

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your ajax *dataType* to `JSON` to access json data from `ajax json response`

```
$.ajax({
    url : "ajaxurl", // insert your ajax URL
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function (d) {
        $.each(d,function(i,v){
            console.log(v);
        });
    }
})
```